# Pycord (Discord Bot) Inside Django View

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, discord.py, pycord

So, I run a rather larger discord bot (couple thousand users atm, trying to grow it). On the same server, I have a Django instance that I use for model storage and web dev. I'm trying to implement an admin panel using some of the model information, but also some information from the discord API. Unfortunately, however, the way that Pycord/Discord.py bots are started, the function is continuous, so I can't just run things normally. So to get the Discord information in a view, I'm attempting this.

```
async def baseAdmin(request):
    intents = discord.Intents.default()
    intents.members = True
    intents.messages = True
    intents.guilds = True
    intents.presences = True
    bot = discord.Bot(intents=intents)
    print('1')

    @bot.event
    async def on_ready():
        print('3')
        n = bot.get_guild(815846750652465202)
        name = n.name
        await bot.close();
        print("4")
        return render(request, 'website/success.html')
    
print("2")
bot.run("MYTOKEN");
```

However, nothing works. I've tried going back and forth between sync and async views, using bot.run with and without an await, and a couple more things. Alas, nothing works. With this specific set, I'm getting an asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError result, but errors have been all over the place. Any assistance is GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: have you tried this? https://github.com/lovvskillz/python-discord-webhook

Comment: @NunoNelas unfortunately that just sends messages and can't access the API to pull data from my understanding

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways that this could be done. You can use something like `redis` and process messages in burst mode inside of a async loop part of the discord bot. If you are using `discord.py` you can do this in cog like so:

```
class RedisCog(commands.Cog):
    @tasks.loop(seconds=10.0)
    async def outbox_loop(self):
        while msg := REDIS_CONNECTION.rpop('QUEUE'):
            await my_func(json.loads(msg))
```

and you can push messages from your Django server via:

```
def push_message_for_channel(value):
    envelope = json.dumps(value)
    REDIS_CONNECTION.rpush('QUEUE', envelope)
```

You can also get a similar functionality using https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ . You can run your discord bot in a `channel`'s worker and then communicate with it via channel layer's.

The information on channel workers is here: https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/worker.html

A very basic implementation can look like:

```
from channels.consumer import AsyncConsumer
from my_bot_module import bot, token

class BaseDiscordConsumer(AsyncConsumer):
    
    def start_bot(self, event):
        async def runner(bot, bot_token, reconnect):
            async with bot:
                await bot.start(bot_token, reconnect=reconnect)
        bot_coro = runner(bot, token, True)
        asyncio.create_task(bot_coro)

    def bot_message(self, event):
        await bot.get_channel(event['channel_id').send(
            content=event['content']
        )
```

And then you would use the channel's command `runworker` to launch this worker and keep it alive. You can then communicate with it from inside Django views with:

```
from channels.layers import get_channel_layer

# When you want to start the bot
channel = get_channel_layer()
await channel.send(
    your_channel_layer_in_asgi_py,
    {
        'type': 'start.bot',
    }
)

# When you want to send a message
channel = get_channel_layer()
await channel.send(
    your_channel_layer_in_asgi_py,
    {
        'type': 'bot.message',
        'channel_id': the_channel_id,
        'content': the_message_content,
    }
)
```

You may need to use `async_to_sync` depending on where in django you are calling from.

A disclaimer, I am the maintainer of https://pypi.org/project/django-discord-py/ which provides some of this functionality for you, if you don't want to implement it yourself.

Comment: For communication from the bot process back to the Django view you can use async Redis's pubsub. There is an example in their documentation here https://redis.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/asyncio_examples.html#Pub/Sub-Mode